# Improving a MySQL query that result in a Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a table that tracks the action of my users (used for logging and debugging for their purpose).

From time to time, I need to mark the data as treated by doing the following call :

```
UPDATE actions
SET is_treated = 1
WHERE code = 200
    AND is_treated = 0
    AND account_uuid = :uuid
    AND DATE(executed) = UTC_DATE()
LIMIT 1000
```

I do that command inside a loop that loop as long as there are "is_treated" at 0 for that day. I limited to 1000 to fasten the query.

That table currently have around 1M entries.

Despite setting the limit at 1000, the query fails from time to time with...

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I tried reducing the limit to 100, with the same error.

For information, the table as the following indexes :

```
$> SHOW INDEX FROM actions;

+-------------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                  | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| actions |          0 | PRIMARY                   |            1 | id           | A         |      952794 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| actions |          1 | account_uuid              |            1 | account_uuid | A         |         696 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| actions |          1 | api_token                 |            1 | api_token    | A         |         848 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| actions |          1 | ix_actions_code       |            1 | code         | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| actions |          1 | ix_actions_executed   |            1 | executed     | A         |      952794 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| actions |          1 | ix_actions_is_treated |            1 | is_treated   | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Is there a way to optimize the query to be run processed faster ?

I was wondering if doing something like the follow would not be faster.

```
UPDATE actions
SET is_treated = 1
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM actions
    WHERE code = 200
        AND is_treated = 0
        AND account_uuid = :uuid
        AND DATE(executed) = UTC_DATE()
    LIMIT 1000
);
```

What do you recommend?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You know you can have more than one column in an index, right? You probably also know that too many indexes on a table hurt update performance.

Comment: Not really. I must confess I'm not that great on handling database performance (hence my request here). Things aren't as obvious for me, sorry. I hesitate between dropping "code" and "is_treated" (based on their cardinality) - or - dropping is_treated, code and executed, and creating one index for all three. But I'm not sure which one is the best

Comment: Guessing that `is_treated`, `account_uuid`, and `DATE(executed)` are all pretty relaxed filters on their own but together reduces the data set quite a lot? In that case, you want one index that covers all 3 columns. The waiting for lock is probably because the index it is using is leading it to get locks on rows that are already locked - the `DATE(executed) = UTC_DATE()` looks like it is targeting rows for today - ie the ones that are currently being inserted.

Comment: Is it good if I keep the index for account_uuid, date, and create a new one with the combination ?

Comment: Welp I tried that, but I still have the same issue ...

Comment: I'm digging on the issue, and discovered that it's the `Update` that is messing up. Searching the IDS related to one account using the above filter returned 3 results! I then did a `UPDATE actions SET is_treated = 1 WHERE id IN (22106886, 22107054, 22111579);`, and got a Lock Timeout !

Comment: Continuing on my search, I listed the process list, killed all the commands like the initial `UPDATE` and re-tried. The only process present anymore are adding (INSERT INTO). Still, the request failed (with the `id IN (id1, 2, 3)`)

Comment: I quit the current connection, re-connected and rerun the query, no success.

Comment: @AndrewSayer I'm blocked trying to understand why on earth I can't run a basic UPDATE query with only 3 values. All the "lock wait timeout" recommandations I found doesn't seem to apply to my issue :/

Comment: If you're filtering on the primary key for this update and it's timing out waiting for the lock, you have some long running transaction in another session which has already taken out the lock on at least one of these rows. Perhaps some application process has crashed after taking locks out or someone has gone for an extended coffee break

Comment: Searching with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` only shows sleeping queries. But running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G` returns two transaction actives : one with "4 lock struct" and another with "2825 lock struct". I'm going to kill these, but I've already done that, and retrying later still fail

Comment: @AndrewSayer I confirm. If I kill all the locked transaction and retry, it sometimes work, sometimes not, and when it fails, it does with small queries like updating less than 5 IDs.

Comment: Here's a line from the innodb status: `---TRANSACTION 5457235, ACTIVE 126 sec
2825 lock struct(s), heap size 319608, 11685 row lock(s), undo log entries 2991
MySQL thread id 52262, OS thread handle 139905473255168, query id 9344382 server_name {ip} {user}`

Comment: This process under the "Show full processlist" returns a "Sleep" command with Time at 0.

Comment: I also noticed that it's impossible to run the update via the code, even with less than 5 Ids, but if I copy that query and run it in the console, it works fine

Comment: OK I GOT IT! I was using two distinct connections in the code between loading the list of IDS (using a read instance) and updating (using a write). I suspect the read was keeping the connection, causing the lock, and the update couldn't finish. By using the write for both, the issue was solved!

Comment: @mustaccio - Only one column changes, so only indexes involving that one column are affected.  Hence, not "too many indexes".  (At least not for that reason.)

Comment: What was the competing transaction that led this Update to timeout?  Take note of them before killing them.

Answer (score 1):

**Sargable**

If the datatype of `executed` is `DATE`, then remove the function call.  If it is `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`, then change the test to:

```
    executed >= UTC_DATE()
AND executed  < UTC_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

In addition, you need this **composite index:**

```
INDEX(account_uuid, code,  -- in any order
      executed)            -- last
```

This index should significantly speed up the `UPDATE`.

(I am guessing that only one row is affected??)

**1000**

Are you looping through a lot of rows, doing 1000 at a time?  How long is each iteration taking?  Decrease the "1000" so that it does takes only a few seconds.

**Building good index:**  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

In almost all cases, MySQL will use only one index in one [sub]query.